# Creating Shared Sharepoint Sites

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I’m working with the .NET Microsoft Graph SDK, and I had a question about the best way to create a Sharepoint Site that is accessible by all members that are part of a tenant. I’m currently creating a Group and using the Group's root Site:

```
GraphServiceClient client = GetGraphClient();

Group group = await client.Groups.Request().AddAsync(new Microsoft.Graph.Group
{
        DisplayName = "A display name",
        Description = "Description",
        MailEnabled = false,
        MailNickname = "a_mail_nickname",
        SecurityEnabled = false,
        GroupTypes = new[]{"Unified"}
});

Site site = await client.Groups[groupId.ToString()].Sites["root"].Request().GetAsync();

//create file using site.Id as the target
```

Will taking this approach prevent other members of the Sharepoint tenant from being able to access the Site? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically access the [group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), below mentioned permission is needed.

[image]

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), to access the team site for a group, below mentioned permission is needed.

[image]